# Add all elements with the same class to list with selenium and python

Tags: python, html, selenium

How do I add all of the elements in a webpage to a list (array) in python with selenium?
Ive tried things like:

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("classname")

list = driver.find_elements(by="class", "classname")
```

When i print the list after this, it only shows [].

Comment: Functions are correct, are you sure you are specifying correctly the classname? Do not name your variable `list`, it shadows the Python `list()` function

Comment: Are you looking for an element whose class name is "classname"?

Comment: Always post relevant HTML and expected output for better solution?

Comment: how you printing the list?

Comment: Just print(list)

Comment: And the class name is correct, and its not called list, but it doesnt work...

Comment: are you trying to do something like this-    `for elem in list: 
    print elem.text`

Answer (score 0):

You can print elements from list using the below approach :

```
list  = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("classname")
for item in list:
    print (item.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found out worked, was doing

```
list_of_elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="classname"]')
```

Then I did

```
names = []
for i in range(len(list_of_elements)):
   names.append(list_of_elements[i].text)
```